# How to reproduce a browser handshake in c# to a websocket without receiving a 403?

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm building a c# application that connects to a websocket using WebSocket-sharp and I keep receiving a 403 - Forbidden from the server.

I have tried using fiddler to see how the browser handle it differently and I have copied all the local cookies the website is using.

The request:

```
GET /api/trade/live/Metamorph/lg8jphV HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: websocket-sharp/1.0
Host: www.pathofexile.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: pnjDDw0njbxi4PmLR+A6OA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Cookie: POESESSID=<redacted>
```

The response:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Sun, 02 Feb 2020 20:32:32 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d31e2345f42cc565e3bbc5e9a2d0ede691580675552; expires=Tue, 03-Mar-20 20:32:32 GMT; path=/; domain=.pathofexile.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
X-Rate-Limit-Policy: trade-websocket-request-limit
X-Rate-Limit-Rules: Ip
X-Rate-Limit-Ip: 45:60:60,90:120:3600
X-Rate-Limit-Ip-State: 1:60:0,1:120:0
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 55eeef5a1ec4919e-EWR
```

Any ideas on what would be the next step in troubleshooting the issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you test, whether a trailing slash helps? `/api/trade/live/Metamorph/lg8jphV` versus `/api/trade/live/Metamorph/lg8jphV/`  headers are also identical?

Comment: You may have to masquerade as a browser User Agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at that particular API, and you first have to create a 'search'. That is what your lg8jphV is - the endpoint has to actually exist before you can open it. In my test, for example, my websocket URL is `wss://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/live/Metamorph/Ab3LSL`

First post your search to `https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/search/Metamorph`. Your body should look something like this (except with your specific search terms):

```
{
    "query": {
        "status": {
            "option": "online"
        },
        "stats": [
            {
                "type": "and",
                "filters": []
            }
        ],
        "filters": {
            "type_filters": {
                "disabled": false,
                "filters": {
                    "category": {
                        "option": "weapon.bow"
                    }
                }
            },
            "misc_filters": {
                "disabled": false,
                "filters": {
                    "shaper_item": {
                        "option": "true"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "price": "asc"
    }
}
```

This creates your actual search object, and you get a response body back like this:

```
{
    "result": [
        "48c83eb427f369f6ddde8689d7458f6bf5a8380eed114b72b5a7a298651c4d65",
        "6314ac7c88b143b80c777d23cdc12bb9d86e8bb82d8073f659132bf492fa69fe",
        "1c39870f03505acaecd78dc0cc2a498a3a1037cd88b0035e3601e35140b59450",
        "3dc8cf428d842a8be12953c6d2db117e5db4456cb6d3b75f5280ca8fb687c587",
        "9470cc63efbe4ca192103200ad78734784a218c68b9d9ead0be456a98260394f",
        "798ba0699085a63359c459cc89cafbbe28653fe893dfb6a9ba71162fd4d7aa51",
        "dab3edc9c28723decc76ba56eb988c7f245ce15041640dca461124918dafbc90",
        "06da5889c8cbf295ab13e103dfa9e291b3e0caf0256b398ccaec9ddfdb1e56c4",
        "... continues ..."
    ],
    "id": "Ab3LSL",
    "total": 100000,
    "inexact": true
}
```

You now have a search endpoint via the ID.

Finally, when making the request, you have to set the Origin header or you'll get a 403 Forbidden (you'll have to change the nuget package you're using to https://www.nuget.org/packages/websocket-sharp-customheaders if you want to keep using websocket-sharp). Don't forget your cookie or you'll get 401 Unauthorized

```cs
using (ClientWebSocket ws = new ClientWebSocket())
{
    Uri serverUri = new Uri($"wss://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/live/Metamorph/D4bWwf5");
    //setting headers the way I did below only works because I used reflection to change the IsRequestRestricted bool to false
    ws.Options.SetRequestHeader("Cookie", "__cfduid=d4a76bfa2583a39474272974006edad461580748134; _ga=GA1.2.477754083.1580748162; _gid=GA1.2.2011499591.1580748162; stored_data=1; _sm_au_c=krZJcAOlyMvVNsrvCJ4mJyGIu8S0KVB4Lr7aqcW0VB9UgAAAAa68dX6r0DT/Ta5U0B4NfCgZ2Jm/2q8R651XMxiBtJsM=; cf_clearance=e6964bd6eaed12c405c1b9b8a2b2f08d506b4926-1580761181-0-150; POESESSID=a2c44ee2111904215ccef8c69b2e72b5");
    ws.Options.SetRequestHeader("Origin", "https://www.pathofexile.com");
    ws.ConnectAsync(serverUri, CancellationToken.None).Wait();

    Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        ArraySegment<byte> inbound = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
        while (ws.State == System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketState.Open) 
        {
            var wsRes = await ws.ReceiveAsync(inbound, CancellationToken.None);
            if (wsRes?.Count > 0)
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inbound.Array, 0, wsRes.Count));
        }
    });

    Console.WriteLine("WEB SOCKET OPEN; HIT ENTER TO EXIT");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You can run the snippet above, just swap out the cookies for your own cookies. This is also just a rough proof of concept using the built in websocket client.

Screenshot of output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I believe the ID already exist since I can type it directly in the url bar and access it without having to redo the search first.

Comment: Thanks, will try it tonight. Please remove your POESESSID or someone else could log into the forum and pose as you.

Comment: I got it working using the WebSocket-sharp library. I had to set my websocket origin to "https://www.pathofexile.com". Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Nerdz - I'll be deleting my account now; I only created it because you have to be authenticated to do the live search. Thanks for the warning though, and glad to hear you got it working :) Didn't realize the WebSocket-sharp library had been updated to include the ability to set headers; the owner of the library was very against it

Comment: Sorry to necro an old thread, but I do receive a different error now "Socket closed:1008" right after I receive the "auth":true. Do you know how to troubleshoot it? Thanks!